# How do I use automatic variables in makefile conditionals?

Tags: makefile, conditional-statements

**Summarize the problem**
I would like to change the compilation for a single source file, like so:

```
%.exe: %.c
ifeq($@, cannon.exe)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(patsubst %.exe,%,$@) $^ $(inc_flags) $(LDLIBS)
else
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(patsubst %.exe,%,$@) $^
endif
```

but it doesn't work!

**Describe what you’ve tried**
I have tried getting bash conditionals involved, but I couldn't figure it out and I shouldn't have to mix bash and make.

**Here's the full Makefile:**

```
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -g -Wall -Wextra
LDLIBS := -lm
inc_dirs := math.h stdio.h
inc_flags := $(addprefix -I,$(inc_dirs))

executable:=cannon.exe
source:=$(executable:%.exe=%.cpp)

.DELETE_ON_ERROR:
all: $(executable)

%.exe: %.c
ifeq($@, cannon.exe)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(patsubst %.exe,%,$@) $^ $(inc_flags) $(LDLIBS)
else
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(patsubst %.exe,%,$@) $^
endif

clean:
    rm -f $(executable:%.exe=%)
```

Comment: This cannot work.  Automatic variables are only defined within the recipe.  Make conditionals are not part of the recipe.  You can tell because they don't begin with a TAB character; anything that doesn't start with a TAB is not part of the recipe (regardless of where in the makefile it appears).  If you need to do this you'll have to use shell conditionals not makefile conditionals.  But, as you discovered, you don't need to do this.

Comment: Instead of defining `inc_flags` and `LDLIBS` globally, define them as specific to the `cannon.exe` target. Simply add: `cannon.exe: inc_flags := $(addprefix -I,$(inc_dirs))` and `cannon.exe: LDLIBS := -lm` somewhere in your Makefile (just these lines, no recipe). Then use the same recipe for all `.exe`. `$(inc_flags)` and `$(LDLIBS)` will expand as empty strings for all `.exe` targets except for `cannon.exe`. See [the GNU make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific) for a detailed explanation about target-specific variable values.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that if you want to do a special case for a certain source file, you can just define its recipe explicitly! Make will take explicit over implicit rules. Full working code below.

```
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -g -Wall -Wextra
LDLIBS := -lm
inc_dirs := math.h stdio.h
inc_flags := $(addprefix -I,$(inc_dirs))

executable:=cannon.exe
source:=$(executable:%.exe=%.cpp)
# no deps so no objs

.DELETE_ON_ERROR:
all: $(executable)

%.exe: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(patsubst %.exe,%,$@) $^

cannon.exe: cannon.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(patsubst %.exe,%,$@) $^ $(inc_flags) $(LDLIBS)

clean:
    rm -f $(executable:%.exe=%)
```

Answer (score 0):

A better / more make-ish solution is to use [constructed variable names](http://make.mad-scientist.net/constructed-macro-names/), like this:

```
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -g -Wall -Wextra
LDLIBS := -lm

inc_dirs := math.h stdio.h    
cannon_CFLAGS := $(addprefix -I,$(inc_dirs))

executable := cannon.exe
source := $(executable:%.exe=%.cpp)
# no deps so no objs

.DELETE_ON_ERROR:
all: $(executable)

%.exe: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $($*_CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

clean:
        rm -f $(executable:%.exe=%)
```

Notes:

Your rules should always create the same name as the target in the makefile.  It's not right for the target to be named `foo.exe` but the build command creates a file named `foo`.  If you want to create a file named `foo`, then the makefile target should be named `foo`.  Basically you should always create the file contained in the make variable `$@`.

Is it really the case that the *directories* you have are named `math.h` and `stdio.h`?  That's.... bizarre.  And very likely to cause serious problems.  If `math.h` and `stdio.h` are files, then you should not add them with `-I` because `-I` takes *directory* names, in which to search file files.  It doesn't take filenames.

If you really did create local files named `math.h` and `stdio.h`, that's also a very bad idea: those are standard header file names and you shouldn't redeclare them yourself unless you really know what you're doing.

If you didn't create these files and you're just trying to include the standard headers `math.h` and `stdio.h` in your file, then you definitely don't need to add any flags to your compile line.  Just include them.